# Specific Android Bluetooth Server issue

Tags: android, python, bluetooth

I have a very particular Android Bluetooth issue:

I have a device (with almost no documentation) that acts as a Bluetooth Client and tries to connect (after pairing) to a Bluetooth Server that listens using the UUID "1234". I have tested in advance using a python script, that the device works and that it connects to the server. The relevant code from the script is:

```
import bluetooth

uuid = "1234"

pc = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)

pc.bind(("", bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
pc.listen(1)

port = pc.getsockname()[1]
print 'Active RFCOMM port: ', port, '\r\n'

bluetooth.advertise_service( pc, "Server",
   service_id = uuid,
   service_classes = [ uuid, bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
   profiles = [ bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ] 
)

print 'Waiting for connection...\r\n'
address = pc.accept()
print 'Accepting connection from: ', address, '\r\n'
```

I am trying to create a similar server on Android using a BluetoothServerSocket. I have converted the 16-bit UUID ("1234"), according to this [article](https://farwestab.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/some-tips-on-android-and-bluetooth/), into "00001234-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB". I have tested with a python script that the server is valid and that I can connect to it using the specified UUID. The code used is pretty standard, as it can be found in many examples across the internet:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    Timber.i("Start Server");
    try {
        final BluetoothServerSocket bluetoothServer = adapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord("Server", mUUID);
        Timber.i("Server Started: " + mUUID.toString());

        BluetoothSocket socket = bluetoothServer.accept();
        Timber.i("Socket initiated: " + socket.getRemoteDevice().getName());

        bluetoothServer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Timber.e("Error starting server: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I have tried with both `listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord` and `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord`. I have made sure the phone and the device are paired and that the phone is discoverable. I have tried with different phones with different OS versions (2.3.7, 4.0.3, 4.4.2, 5.1.0), as I thought that the change of the Bluetooth stack in Android 4.2 was the issue. Nothing seems to make the device to connect to my phone. I can also provide a hci dump from my Nexus 5 captured when the device was trying to connect, but I wasn't able to identify the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

This is the python code used to verify the Android Bluetooth Server:

```
import sys
import bluetooth

uuid = "1234"
service_matches = bluetooth.find_service( uuid = uuid )

if len(service_matches) == 0:
    print "couldn't find the service"
    sys.exit(0)

first_match = service_matches[0]
port = first_match["port"]
name = first_match["name"]
host = first_match["host"]

print "connecting to \"%s\" on %s" % (name, host)

sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((host, port))
sock.send("Test")
sock.close()
```

Needless to say that it worked without any issues.

Comment: Please post your client code too?

Answer (score 0):

By the off chance that someone else runs into this type of issue, it turns out the Bluetooth Client device was only connecting to the server if it had a certain [bluetooth device class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.html), which was evidently not the smart phone one.